# C# What is the difference between byte[] and char[]

Tags: c#, arrays

What is the difference between byte[] and char[]?

Differentiate more from usage perspective. Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Lookup the difference between [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(VS.71).aspx) and [char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: One is an array of bytes, the other an array of char. What is the question here?

Comment: This honestly sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: One is an 8-bit integer the other is a unicode character.  The character represented by unicode value of say '1' is different then the binary value of 1.  The binary value of unicode character '1' would be significantly higher then the binary value of 1.

Comment: @JonH: I am definitely newbie to C# but left school 12yr back. Would love to go back though :-)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`byte` represents a byte. It is always 8-bits wide. `char` represents a unicode character, and thus is two bytes (i.e. 16 bits) wide. Use `byte[]` if you're dealing with raw bytes, and `char[]` (or better yet `string`) if you're dealing with strings.

Comment: Its nice you provided a nice answer but this sounds suspicious of homework and it looks like you did his work for him.

Comment: I'm usually pretty careful to avoid answering homework (and you can look through my comments history to confirm,) but you could be right. Honestly, though, this information is so eminently Google-able that even if it is HW, the amount assistance is minimal. If this was academic in nature, I would expect this question to be on a test, rather than an HW assignment. But again, my mistake if I'm wrong.

Comment: I am not sure why people are so disturbed on this "Homework" idea. I just had a question, so asked. I thought that's the purpose of this site??

Comment: @ceonikka Don't worry about it; StackOverflow is indeed for getting programming-related questions answered. Because of that, there are a lot of questions from students who have slacked off on homework assignments and are hoping that someone here can do it for them. That's obviously not the goal here, so people are always vigilant about screening homework questions, and especially those questions where it's clear no prepatory work has been done.

Comment: +1 here. Forgot the difference, needed to quickly brush up on the basics without reading lengthy tomes. Clear question and clear answer as it should be.

Comment: Word of advise, word your question wisely,

Comment: @JonH FYI I am just moved to C# from c++, and have no idea should I use «char» e.g. for a buffer to receive a network packet, either I should use «byte». It isn't clear to me at all that «char» is two byte size in C#. Also you should know that Unicode have different versions too, e.g. in GNU/Linux used one-byte version(UTF-8), consequently it isn't even clear why the size of «char» is two bytes: C# is a cross platform language despite being hated by many ones on a platforms different from Windows®.